# SAPUI5 sap.m.list in a popover is emtpy when populated using bindElement

Tags: sapui5, popover

I have a table (sap.m.table) with different columns. One columns contains a link and when the user clicks on the link a popover fragment opens and shows some details in a list (sap.m.list). The data is coming from an oData Service. One Entity feeds the table and through a navigation property the data for the popover is fetched.

I have a working example for this scenario where I create the the list template in the controller. But I believe that this should also be possible just by xml and a bindElement in the controller. What is the mistake in my second scenario?

**First Scenario** (which is working fine):
Popover XML:

```
    <Popover
    showHeader="false"
    contentWidth="320px"
    contentHeight="300px"
    placement="Bottom"
    ariaLabelledBy="master-title">
        <Page
            id="master"
            class="sapUiResponsivePadding--header"
            title="Aktionen">
            <List
                id="AktionList">                    
            </List>
        </Page>
</Popover>
```

Calling the Popover in the controller file (sPath is /TableEntity('123456')/AktionSet):

```
if (!this._oPopover) {
Fragment.load({
    id: "popoverNavCon",
    name: "bernmobil.ZPM_STOERUNG_FDA.view.AktionPopover",
    controller: this
}).then(function(oPopover){
    this._oPopover = oPopover;
    this.getView().addDependent(this._oPopover);
    
    var oList = Fragment.byId("popoverNavCon", "AktionList");
    var oItemTemplate = this._BuildItemTemplate();
    oList.bindAggregation("items", sPath, oItemTemplate);
    this._oPopover.openBy(oControl);
  }.bind(this));
} else {
    var oList = Fragment.byId("popoverNavCon", "AktionList");
    var oItemTemplate = this._BuildItemTemplate();
        oList.bindAggregation("items", sPath, oItemTemplate);
    this._oPopover.openBy(oControl);
}
_BuildItemTemplate: function(){
        var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.ObjectListItem({
            title:"{AktionsBez}", 
            type: "Inactive"              
        });
        
        oItemTemplate.addAttribute(new sap.m.ObjectAttribute({
            text : "{Aktionstext}"
        }));
        oItemTemplate.addAttribute(new sap.m.ObjectAttribute({
            text : "{path: 'ChangedAt', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.DateTime'}"
        }));
        return oItemTemplate;       
    }
```

And this is the idea of the **second scenario** which is calling the oDataService but not displaying any data:
Instead of having only the List definition in XML also the ObjectListItem is defined in the XML:

```
<List
    id="AktionList"
    items="{AktionSet}"> 
    <ObjectListItem 
        title="{AktionsBez}"
        type="Active">
        <ObjectAttribute text="{Aktionstext}" />
        <ObjectAttribute text="{ChangedAt}" />
    </ObjectListItem>
</List>
```

And in the controller instead of building the template and doing the bindAggretation there is just:

```
var oList = Fragment.byId("popoverNavCon", "AktionList");
oList.bindElement(sPath);
```

How do I get the second scenario displaying data in the list?

Comment: Maybe the sPath is wrong, it should be "/AktionSet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a third solution:

When pressing on your table row, get the binding context of the current row using `oContext = oClickedRow.getBindingContext()` or something similar. This context should point to `/TableEntity('123456')`.

Apply this context to your `Popover` using `oPopover.setBindingContext(oContext)`.

Now your `Popover` has the same context as your table row. The XML should look like in your second scenario.

Using the path is an extra step imo.  I think it also makes more sense to bind the complete `Popover` and not just the `List`. Has the neat side effect that you can use a property of your `TableEntity` as the title for the `Popover`. It also completely avoids working with controls directly (which is one of the seven deadly sins) and you should be able to remove all those IDs.

Comment: Just did as you suggested and it works perfectly fine and I could get rid of the IDs in the fragment.
Can you explain me why the navigation property works when I do setBindingContext and the list items point to (AktionSet}. Is this because of the relative binding {AktionSet} (without the /) and the root is the /TableEntity('123456') of the bound context?

Comment: And could you point me to some more information about the deadly sin of using IDs. I am aware that it can create issues, but never looked at it as such bad practice.

Comment: Yes, that's how binding works. If you provide a relative path (no slash) it will check if there is a surrounding context and append the relative path to that.

Comment: I think IDs create a tight bond between XML and JS which is not necessary. This makes the code less reusable. This also makes refactorings harder. Your list becomes a table? You also have to rename your ID to AktionTable. I heard an interesting talk at this years UI5Con, basically everything can be done without IDs and it makes your code more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the relevant part of the view should look:

```
<List
    id="AktionList"
    items="{AktionSet}"> 
    <dependents>
        <ObjectListItem 
            id="oObjectListItem"
            title="{AktionsBez}"
            type="Active">
            <ObjectAttribute text="{Aktionstext}" />
            <ObjectAttribute text="{ChangedAt}" />
        </ObjectListItem>
    </dependents>
</List>
```

And in the controller:

```
var oList = sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId(this.getView().createId("popoverNavCon"), "AktionList");
oList.bindItems({
    path: sPath,
    template: sap.ui.core.Fragment.byId(this.getView().createId("popoverNavCon"), "oObjectListItem")
});
```

Check `dependents` in [`sap.m.List` aggregation](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.List%23aggregations) section for details.